# JSON_PARSER_ERROR - "message": "Unknown field:

Tags: apex, json

I've spent some time on here trying to figure out the error but I'm still running into this error that I can't figure out.

I'm trying to parse a JSON using the JSON2Apex online tool. I've gotten it to work in the past, but now I am only receiving this error in Postman:

[
{
"message": "Unknown field: PropertyApplicationm_JSON2Apex.newApplications at [line:3, column:29]",
"errorCode": "JSON_PARSER_ERROR"
}
]

This is the JSON file:

```
    {
    "JsonStuff": {
        "newApplications": [
            {
                "id": "YMCUQY",
                "answers": {
                    "represent": {
                        "represent": "Myself"
                    },
                    "applicantType": {
                        "individual": "individual"
                    },
                    "contactIndividual": {
                        "name": "Edgar",
                        "email": "edgar@email.com",
                        "phone": "31312345678",
                        "address": "1301 X Ave",
                        "city": "Detroit",
                        "state": "MI",
                        "zip_code": "48226",
                        "country": "US"
                    },
                    "DLBACommunityPartner": {
                        "DLBACommunityPartner": "No"
                    },
                    "LLCs": {
                        "llc_entities_0": ""
                    },
                    "ownPropertyinDetroit": {
                        "ownPropertyinDetroit": "No"
                    },
                    "delinquencyStatus": {
                        "delinquencyStatus": "No"
                    },
                    "identifiedProperty": {
                        "identifiedProperty": "Yes"
                    },
                    "interestedProperty": {
                        "interested_property_0": "1104 X, 48209",
                        "interested_property_0_parcel": "12345678."
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "id": "YMCUQY",
                "answers": {
                    "represent": {
                        "represent": "Myself"
                    },
                    "applicantType": {
                        "individual": "individual"
                    },
                    "contactIndividual": {
                        "name": "Edgar",
                        "email": "edgar@email.com",
                        "phone": "31312345678",
                        "address": "1301 X Ave",
                        "city": "Detroit",
                        "state": "MI",
                        "zip_code": "48226",
                        "country": "US"
                    },
                    "DLBACommunityPartner": {
                        "DLBACommunityPartner": "Yes"
                    },
                    "LLCs": {
                        "llc_entities_0": ""
                    },
                    "ownPropertyinDetroit": {
                        "ownPropertyinDetroit": "No"
                    },
                    "delinquencyStatus": {
                        "delinquencyStatus": "No"
                    },
                    "identifiedProperty": {
                        "identifiedProperty": "Yes"
                    },
                    "interestedProperty": {
                        "interested_property_0": "1104 X, 48209",
                        "interested_property_0_parcel": "12345678."
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And this is the code provided by JSON2Apex:

```
global class PropertyApplicationm_JSON2Apex {

    global class Represent {
        global String represent {get;set;} 

        global Represent(JSONParser parser) {
            while (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
                if (parser.getCurrentToken() == System.JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                    String text = parser.getText();
                    if (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                        if (text == 'represent') {
                            represent = parser.getText();
                        } else {
                            System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'Represent consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                            consumeObject(parser);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    global class OwnPropertyinDetroit {
        global String ownPropertyinDetroit {get;set;} 

        global OwnPropertyinDetroit(JSONParser parser) {
            while (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
                if (parser.getCurrentToken() == System.JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                    String text = parser.getText();
                    if (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                        if (text == 'ownPropertyinDetroit') {
                            ownPropertyinDetroit = parser.getText();
                        } else {
                            System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'OwnPropertyinDetroit consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                            consumeObject(parser);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    global JsonStuff JsonStuff {get;set;} 

    global PropertyApplicationm_JSON2Apex(JSONParser parser) {
        while (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
            if (parser.getCurrentToken() == System.JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                String text = parser.getText();
                if (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                    if (text == 'JsonStuff') {
                        JsonStuff = new JsonStuff(parser);
                    } else {
                        System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'PropertyApplicationm_JSON2Apex consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                        consumeObject(parser);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    global class Answers {
        global Represent represent {get;set;} 
        global ApplicantType applicantType {get;set;} 
        global ContactIndividual contactIndividual {get;set;} 
        global DLBACommunityPartner DLBACommunityPartner {get;set;} 
        global LLCs LLCs {get;set;} 
        global OwnPropertyinDetroit ownPropertyinDetroit {get;set;} 
        global DelinquencyStatus delinquencyStatus {get;set;} 
        global IdentifiedProperty identifiedProperty {get;set;} 
        global InterestedProperty interestedProperty {get;set;} 

        global Answers(JSONParser parser) {
            while (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
                if (parser.getCurrentToken() == System.JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                    String text = parser.getText();
                    if (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                        if (text == 'represent') {
                            represent = new Represent(parser);
                        } else if (text == 'applicantType') {
                            applicantType = new ApplicantType(parser);
                        } else if (text == 'contactIndividual') {
                            contactIndividual = new ContactIndividual(parser);
                        } else if (text == 'DLBACommunityPartner') {
                            DLBACommunityPartner = new DLBACommunityPartner(parser);
                        } else if (text == 'LLCs') {
                            LLCs = new LLCs(parser);
                        } else if (text == 'ownPropertyinDetroit') {
                            ownPropertyinDetroit = new OwnPropertyinDetroit(parser);
                        } else if (text == 'delinquencyStatus') {
                            delinquencyStatus = new DelinquencyStatus(parser);
                        } else if (text == 'identifiedProperty') {
                            identifiedProperty = new IdentifiedProperty(parser);
                        } else if (text == 'interestedProperty') {
                            interestedProperty = new InterestedProperty(parser);
                        } else {
                            System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'Answers consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                            consumeObject(parser);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    global class IdentifiedProperty {
        global String identifiedProperty {get;set;} 

        global IdentifiedProperty(JSONParser parser) {
            while (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
                if (parser.getCurrentToken() == System.JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                    String text = parser.getText();
                    if (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                        if (text == 'identifiedProperty') {
                            identifiedProperty = parser.getText();
                        } else {
                            System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'IdentifiedProperty consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                            consumeObject(parser);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    global class NewApplications {
        global String id {get;set;} 
        global Answers answers {get;set;} 

        global NewApplications(JSONParser parser) {
            while (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
                if (parser.getCurrentToken() == System.JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                    String text = parser.getText();
                    if (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                        if (text == 'id') {
                            id = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'answers') {
                            answers = new Answers(parser);
                        } else {
                            System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'NewApplications consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                            consumeObject(parser);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    global class JsonStuff {
        global List<NewApplications> newApplications {get;set;} 

        global JsonStuff(JSONParser parser) {
            while (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
                if (parser.getCurrentToken() == System.JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                    String text = parser.getText();
                    if (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                        if (text == 'newApplications') {
                            newApplications = arrayOfNewApplications(parser);
                        } else {
                            System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'JsonStuff consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                            consumeObject(parser);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    global class DelinquencyStatus {
        global String delinquencyStatus {get;set;} 

        global DelinquencyStatus(JSONParser parser) {
            while (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
                if (parser.getCurrentToken() == System.JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                    String text = parser.getText();
                    if (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                        if (text == 'delinquencyStatus') {
                            delinquencyStatus = parser.getText();
                        } else {
                            System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'DelinquencyStatus consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                            consumeObject(parser);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    global class LLCs {
        global String llc_entities_0 {get;set;} 

        global LLCs(JSONParser parser) {
            while (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
                if (parser.getCurrentToken() == System.JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                    String text = parser.getText();
                    if (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                        if (text == 'llc_entities_0') {
                            llc_entities_0 = parser.getText();
                        } else {
                            System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'LLCs consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                            consumeObject(parser);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    global class ApplicantType {
        global String individual {get;set;} 

        global ApplicantType(JSONParser parser) {
            while (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
                if (parser.getCurrentToken() == System.JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                    String text = parser.getText();
                    if (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                        if (text == 'individual') {
                            individual = parser.getText();
                        } else {
                            System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'ApplicantType consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                            consumeObject(parser);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    global class DLBACommunityPartner {
        global String DLBACommunityPartner {get;set;} 

        global DLBACommunityPartner(JSONParser parser) {
            while (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
                if (parser.getCurrentToken() == System.JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                    String text = parser.getText();
                    if (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                        if (text == 'DLBACommunityPartner') {
                            DLBACommunityPartner = parser.getText();
                        } else {
                            System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'DLBACommunityPartner consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                            consumeObject(parser);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    global class ContactIndividual {
        global String name {get;set;} 
        global String email {get;set;} 
        global String phone {get;set;} 
        global String address {get;set;} 
        global String city {get;set;} 
        global String state {get;set;} 
        global String zip_code {get;set;} 
        global String country {get;set;} 

        global ContactIndividual(JSONParser parser) {
            while (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
                if (parser.getCurrentToken() == System.JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                    String text = parser.getText();
                    if (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                        if (text == 'name') {
                            name = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'email') {
                            email = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'phone') {
                            phone = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'address') {
                            address = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'city') {
                            city = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'state') {
                            state = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'zip_code') {
                            zip_code = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'country') {
                            country = parser.getText();
                        } else {
                            System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'ContactIndividual consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                            consumeObject(parser);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    global class InterestedProperty {
        global String interested_property_0 {get;set;} 
        global String interested_property_0_parcel {get;set;} 

        global InterestedProperty(JSONParser parser) {
            while (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
                if (parser.getCurrentToken() == System.JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                    String text = parser.getText();
                    if (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                        if (text == 'interested_property_0') {
                            interested_property_0 = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'interested_property_0_parcel') {
                            interested_property_0_parcel = parser.getText();
                        } else {
                            System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'InterestedProperty consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                            consumeObject(parser);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    global static PropertyApplicationm_JSON2Apex parse(String json) {
        System.JSONParser parser = System.JSON.createParser(json);
        return new PropertyApplicationm_JSON2Apex(parser);
    }
    
    global static void consumeObject(System.JSONParser parser) {
        Integer depth = 0;
        do {
            System.JSONToken curr = parser.getCurrentToken();
            if (curr == System.JSONToken.START_OBJECT || 
                curr == System.JSONToken.START_ARRAY) {
                depth++;
            } else if (curr == System.JSONToken.END_OBJECT ||
                curr == System.JSONToken.END_ARRAY) {
                depth--;
            }
        } while (depth > 0 && parser.nextToken() != null);
    }
    





    private static List<NewApplications> arrayOfNewApplications(System.JSONParser p) {
        List<NewApplications> res = new List<NewApplications>();
        if (p.getCurrentToken() == null) p.nextToken();
        while (p.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_ARRAY) {
            res.add(new NewApplications(p));
        }
        return res;
    }

}
```

Thank you for any insight!

Comment: This file does not seem like what you would have passed to `JSON2Apex`, as the `newApplications` attribute is indeed missing from your model.

Comment: @AdrianLarson thank you, i ran the json back through JSON2Apex and updated the code in the post but i'm still getting the same error